# Filter an array every time a function is executed and my react state change

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, filter

I'm working on a project that has to do with playlist, so what I want to execute is whenever one of the songs on the playlist is clicked the image that is attached to the song should be viewed.
So, I have my code this way...

```
const Component = () => {
  const value = useContext(DataContext);

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url =
      "https://52-90-82-235.maverickmaven.com/geotourdata/json.cfm?h=-107,37,s,en,3A771765";

    const currentValue = value;

    axios({
      method: "get",
      url,
      responseType: "stream",
    }).then((response) => {
      let features = response.data.features.filter((elem) => {
        return elem.type === "Feature";
      });

      setData(features);

      const currentDatafile = data?.filter((data) => {
        return data?.assets[0].audio === value;
      });
      setCurrentData(currentDatafile);
    });
  }, [setCurrentData]);
};
```

So, what this code does is that it returns the array that has the picture, but the problem is that it only filters once and repeatedly returns the same value even if I click on another song, and I need it to filter every time I clicked on the songs(i.e the function is executed).

I tried filtering and mapping at the same time, but it didn't work. or maybe I didn't write the syntax well enough.

Please I need help.

Comment: What does `features` contain when you `console.log()` it?

Comment: It returns an array, that contains the data that i want to loop through.

Comment: so, i saved  the data value by using setData(feature), so i can then use data to navigate to where i want in the array, but this time i want to filter it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move these lines to new useEffect hook. Will trigger after you set data

```
useEffect(() => {
  const currentDatafile = data?.filter((item) => {
    return item.assets[0].audio === value;
  });
  setCurrentData(currentDatafile)},[data])
```

Comment: I tried it this, it's the same thing, the function works but only did once, even if i click on the song again is still display the same file over and over again, which means that it wasn't updated, that's the issue here..

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't re-fetch the data from the remote source every time. I've wrapped that in a custom hook instead, here (and a custom fetcher function to make testing/mocking easier).

Then, you shouldn't hold the selected object in the state unless you need to modify it internally (in which case you should copy it into a state atom anyway); instead, just hold the ID.

```js
function fetchTourData() {
  return fetch('https://52-90-82-235.maverickmaven.com/geotourdata/json.cfm?h=-107,37,s,en,3A771765')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => data.features.filter((elem) => elem.type === 'Feature'));
}

function useTourData() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchTourData().then(setData);
  }, [setData]);
  return data;
}

const Component = () => {
  const tourData = useTourData();
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = React.useState(null);
  const selectedTour = (tourData || []).find(t => t.id === selectedId);
  if (tourData === null) {
    return <div>Loading</div>
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Selected: {JSON.stringify(selectedTour || "nothing")}
      </div>
      <ul>
        {tourData.map(t => <li key={t.id}><a href="#" onClick={() => setSelectedId(t.id)}>{t.name}</a></li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: what happens when your `find()` has resolved but tourData is still null. Showing loading state in that case would be wrong

Comment: @Aquib the `selectedTour` assignment could be moved after the if - it doesn't matter at all.